# Listing script's file dependencies

Tags: shell-script, filesystems

Given a shell script, is there an easy way to extract what files it manipulates explicitly (so not like concatenating some command and than eval-ing it)?  E.g.

```
 #!/bin/bash

. /etc/someconfig.cfg

    cat /somedir/somefile.txt

    cp /otherdir/file1.txt /tmp/fileABC.txt

    rm -f ~/stupidfile.txt

    #EOF
```

Is there a command that would extract the explicit dependencies so that I don't have to parse the script or do it manually and get output like:

```
/etc/someconfig.cfg    
/somedir/somefile.txt
/otherdir/file1.txt 
/tmp/fileABC.txt
~/stupidfile.txt
```

?

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible in general to examine source code in a reasonably powerful programming language and deduce what external resources it will attempt to use if it is run.

Comment: OK.  i thought there could be a shell interpreter option to extract script metadata dependencies

Answer (score 4):

Parsing the program is a reasonable approach to solve this (especially in an interpreted language).

If you have a static script without branches, you could do an
`strace -e open -f` for the script to see which files it does open.